# paypal payment standard payment method is not visible

Tags: magento-1.8, paypal

I enabled "paypal payment standard" payment method in admin panel but still I can't see the option when I am in Checkout page.

[image]

See how my checkout page is visible without the paypal payment method.

[image]

I am thinking the paypal method should be visible there as I mentioned in image.

what should I do more to make paypal payment method option visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My currency setup was `Indian rupee` and it seems paypal doesn't support Indian currency. When I changed it to `US Dollar`. paypal option become visible.

I was actually moving to `US Dollar`, so this is no problem for me.

PS: The answer was given by user `jspoe` from magento room on IRC chat(freenode).

Comment: Is any possible Paypal for INR?

Answer (score 0):

Now, you can have multiple currency support of paypal in magento, for this you need to configure some setting, I have followed this article and helped me to setup multi currency support for paypal  http://www.magentostack.com/magento-multicurrency-support-for-paypal/

Comment: Hi MagentoExport and welcome to MAgeOverflow. Please don't post link only answers, because there will be a time, were the link will be dead. Please sum up the most important content of the post.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt you are peRFect, now the link is not working :-)